# Sounddevice + big array + OOP = Segfault / Bus Error

Tags: python, audio, python-sounddevice

I'm having a very strange problem, which I managed to reduce as much as possible like this:

```py
import sounddevice
import time

class SamplerBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.samples = {}

    def audio_callback(self, outdata, frame_count, time_info, status):
        print('ac')

    def init(self):
        self.connect_audio_output()
        self.load_samples()
        time.sleep(20)

    def connect_audio_output(self):
        try:
            sd = sounddevice.OutputStream(callback=self.audio_callback)
            sd.start()
            print('Opened audio device')
        except:
            print('Invalid audio device')
            exit(1)

    def load_samples(self):
        for midinote in range(128):
            for velocity in range(128):
                self.samples[midinote, velocity] = Sound()


class Sound:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


sb = SamplerBox()
sb.init()
```

As soon as I create that big `self.samples` dict, and only create a new audio stream with an empty callback, I get "Bus Error 10" with Python 3.11.

With Python 3.9 I get "Illegal instruction 4"

In my original script (reduced here) I got "Segmentation Fault 11"

I'm running Homebrew Python 3.11 on MacOS 10.15.7.

Worst than that, ***written in a procedural way, it runs perfectly*** :

```py
import sounddevice
import time

samples = {}


class Sound:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def audio_callback(self, outdata, frame_count, time_info, status):
    print('ac')


try:
    sd = sounddevice.OutputStream(callback=audio_callback)
    sd.start()
    print('Opened audio device')
except:
    print('Invalid audio device')
    exit(1)

for midinote in range(128):
    for velocity in range(128):
        samples[midinote, velocity] = Sound()

time.sleep(20)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not keep a reference to the output stream object created in `connect_audio_output`, so when the method finishes the `sounddevice.OutputStream` object associated to the **local variable** `sd` loses all its references  and will be eventually collected by the GC.

Keep the object alive, e.g. by assigning it to an instance attribute:

```
def connect_audio_output(self):
    try:
        self.sd = sounddevice.OutputStream(callback=self.audio_callback)
        self.sd.start()
        print('Opened audio device')
    except:
        print('Invalid audio device')
        exit(1)
```

In your procedural approach `sd` **is a global variable**, so the object will persist as long as the process exists.

Comment: Bug segfault etc means something has not been properly destroyed, or some issue with Python isn't it?

Comment: Sounddevice is a binding for PortAudio (c++) using cffi, I guess the error is coming from the c++ code called from python, which tries to use an object that has been destroyed (and its memory freed) by the GC. A segfault indicates that the process is trying to access a memory region which does not belong to it, one of the possible causes is precisely trying to access a memory region previously freed, and therefore available for the OS to allocate it to something else that needs it.